# Meteor app blank on localhost:3000

Tags: meteor, localhost

I have run `meteor` in my applications 100 times, and my apps always render to localhost:3000. right now, though, on one specific app, my browser is blank. Ive hosted it locally before and I can host other applications. additionally, there are no console/terminal errors.

When I view page source, it's blank, but when I inspect elements, it's my code...

I pulled down a version of the project that I know worked on localhost, and I get the exact same thing.

What could be happening?

Comment: did you have some css? wich is blocking the content? how the apps looks? the did you have some `<body>` tag? if is posible do some repo on [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/)

Comment: it was a cache issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It worked for me:

1. > cd to-your-app-dir
2. > meteor npm install
3. > meteor

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a route set for `localhost:3000/`.
See [flow-router](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) or [iron-router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/).

Also double check what your app does during the onCreated() event of your template at `localhost:3000/`.